# Invalid redirect_uri afer setting bind address to non-localhost IP

Tags: jboss, keycloak

I'm developing an application which runs on Keycloak/JBoss. It works, but now I want to test it from another computer. So I set the JBoss command line parameter "-b 0.0.0.0". And after that I can't login to my web interface anymore.

Keycloak says to me "WE'RE SORRY ... Invalid redirect_uri."

And in fact it tries to redirect to localhost all the time.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I simply forgot to change `auth-server-url` in my war file.

Comment: I edited the auth-server-url in the properties file but still does not solve my case..

Comment: i have spring boot app running on the same m/c. i verified the redirect_uri mentioned in the client config of keycloak. no where i have mentioned localhost. but still keycloak keeps redirecting it to localhost :(

Comment: @iwekesi did you find a solution?

Comment: @Atropo, I don't remember what exactly I did. Using reverse proxy server like nginx solved my problem i think. refer this SO question and the comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799864/reverse-proxy-configuration-for-keycloak-nginx